# How can I get JHC to cooperate with the android ndk?

Tags: android, haskell, android-ndk

JHC is a Haskell compiler which portable generates C code and then invokes a compiler backend to make an executable.

I need to dump the header files and libraries for JHC's runtime system, so the android ndk can use it to compile the generated C code.

Alternatively, I need to figure out how to link the android API into JHC.

Basically, how can I plug JHC into the android ndk backend?

Edit: I've made a standalone compiler using one of the ndk's build tools that JHC can use, "build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh" . Now I need to figure  out a way for JHC to compile my program into a shared object library, and how to get JHC to not demand a "main" function.

Edit2: I have the following targets.ini and compile script. Strangely the shared library fails to load.

```
[android]
cc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
cflags+= -shared -fPIC -rdynamic -Wno-all
gc=static
executable_extension=.so
merge=mle32
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh

jhc --cross -mandroid \
 --main=Main.android_main \
 hs/Main.hs -o libs/armeabi/libnative-activity &&   
ant debug &&
ant debug install
```

Comment: Why does the shared library fail to load? Is there an error message? Also, do you load it from a Java application, or you try to call it from C/C++ code (I suspect the later, as you seem to use the NativeActivity)?

Comment: I'm using the native activity glue code. Part of the reason that I'm so frustrated is that the error messages are very unclear. I'm actually curious if there'd be a way to get better ones. There seem only two different ones, one indicating that the library can't be found, (which I fixed), and one indicating the library won't load correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
I didn't put the function call "app_dummy()" at the start of my "android_main" function.

Comment: NOTE: With the new NDKr15 app_dummy() is gone and it will throw an error